# vsftpd filezilla timout error

Tags: ftp

I have an vsftpd setup. When I try to upload a large number of files, a lot of files fail with a timeout error. After some analysis, I saw this pattern as follow before every error, but I don't know what is the cause.

Can anyone throw some light on it?

```
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (50,16,204,201,4,7).
Command:    STOR ms-users.php
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (50,16,204,201,4,0).
Command:    STOR post.php
```

here is a more detailed process, i don't understand the format and the protocal details:

```
 2012-03-18 13:02:52 5608 5 Status: Resolving address of majorchooser.info
2012-03-18 13:02:52 5608 5 Status: Connecting to 50.16.204.201:21...
2012-03-18 13:02:53 5608 5 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2012-03-18 13:02:53 5608 5 Response: 220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
2012-03-18 13:02:53 5608 5 Command: USER majorchooser
2012-03-18 13:02:54 5608 5 Response: 331 Please specify the password.
2012-03-18 13:02:54 5608 5 Command: PASS ***********
2012-03-18 13:02:54 5608 5 Response: 230 Login successful.
2012-03-18 13:02:54 5608 5 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2012-03-18 13:02:55 5608 5 Response: 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
2012-03-18 13:02:55 5608 5 Status: Connected
2012-03-18 13:02:55 5608 5 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2012-03-18 13:02:55 5608 5 Command: PWD
2012-03-18 13:02:55 5608 5 Response: 257 "/"
2012-03-18 13:02:55 5608 5 Status: Directory listing successful
2012-03-18 13:03:01 5608 1 Status: Resolving address of majorchooser.info
2012-03-18 13:03:01 5608 2 Status: Resolving address of majorchooser.info
2012-03-18 13:03:01 5608 1 Status: Connecting to 50.16.204.201:21...
2012-03-18 13:03:01 5608 2 Status: Connecting to 50.16.204.201:21...
2012-03-18 13:03:01 5608 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2012-03-18 13:03:01 5608 2 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2012-03-18 13:03:02 5608 1 Response: 220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
2012-03-18 13:03:02 5608 1 Command: USER majorchooser
2012-03-18 13:03:02 5608 1 Response: 331 Please specify the password.
2012-03-18 13:03:02 5608 1 Command: PASS ***********
2012-03-18 13:03:02 5608 1 Response: 230 Login successful.
2012-03-18 13:03:02 5608 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2012-03-18 13:03:03 5608 1 Response: 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
2012-03-18 13:03:03 5608 1 Status: Connected
2012-03-18 13:03:03 5608 1 Status: Starting upload of D:\websites\tedxnanjing-online\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php
2012-03-18 13:03:03 5608 1 Command: CWD /test-ftp/wp-admin
2012-03-18 13:03:03 5608 1 Response: 550 Failed to change directory.
2012-03-18 13:03:03 5608 1 Command: CWD /test-ftp
2012-03-18 13:03:04 5608 1 Response: 250 Directory successfully changed.
2012-03-18 13:03:04 5608 1 Command: MKD wp-admin
2012-03-18 13:03:04 5608 1 Response: 257 "/test-ftp/wp-admin" created
2012-03-18 13:03:04 5608 1 Command: CWD /test-ftp/wp-admin
2012-03-18 13:03:05 5608 1 Response: 250 Directory successfully changed.
2012-03-18 13:03:05 5608 1 Command: PWD
2012-03-18 13:03:05 5608 1 Response: 257 "/test-ftp/wp-admin"
2012-03-18 13:03:05 5608 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2012-03-18 13:03:05 5608 1 Command: TYPE I
2012-03-18 13:03:06 5608 2 Response: 220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
2012-03-18 13:03:06 5608 2 Command: USER majorchooser
2012-03-18 13:03:06 5608 2 Response: 331 Please specify the password.
2012-03-18 13:03:06 5608 2 Command: PASS ***********
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 1 Response: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 1 Command: PASV
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 2 Response: 230 Login successful.
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 2 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (50,16,204,201,4,186).
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 1 Command: LIST -a
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 2 Response: 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 2 Status: Connected
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 2 Status: Starting upload of D:\websites\tedxnanjing-online\wp-admin\admin-footer.php
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 2 Command: CWD /test-ftp/wp-admin
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 2 Response: 250 Directory successfully changed.
2012-03-18 13:03:07 5608 2 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2012-03-18 13:03:08 5608 1 Response: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
2012-03-18 13:03:08 5608 1 Response: 226 Directory send OK.
2012-03-18 13:03:08 5608 1 Command: TYPE A
2012-03-18 13:03:08 5608 2 Command: TYPE A
2012-03-18 13:03:09 5608 1 Response: 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
2012-03-18 13:03:09 5608 1 Command: PASV
2012-03-18 13:03:09 5608 2 Response: 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
2012-03-18 13:03:09 5608 2 Command: PASV
2012-03-18 13:03:09 5608 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (50,16,204,201,5,251).
2012-03-18 13:03:09 5608 1 Command: STOR admin-ajax.php
2012-03-18 13:03:09 5608 2 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (50,16,204,201,4,185).
2012-03-18 13:03:09 5608 2 Command: STOR admin-footer.php
2012-03-18 13:03:13 5608 1 Response: 150 Ok to send data.
2012-03-18 13:03:19 5608 2 Response: 150 Ok to send data.
2012-03-18 13:03:22 5608 1 Response: 226 Transfer complete.
2012-03-18 13:03:22 5608 1 Status: File transfer successful, transferred 49,808 bytes in 13 seconds
2012-03-18 13:03:22 5608 1 Status: Starting upload of D:\websites\tedxnanjing-online\wp-admin\admin-functions.php
2012-03-18 13:03:22 5608 1 Command: PASV
2012-03-18 13:03:23 5608 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (50,16,204,201,7,142).
2012-03-18 13:03:23 5608 1 Command: STOR admin-functions.php
2012-03-18 13:03:24 5608 1 Response: 150 Ok to send data.
2012-03-18 13:03:39 5608 2 Error: Connection timed out
2012-03-18 13:03:39 5608 2 Error: File transfer failed
2012-03-18 13:03:39 5608 2 Status: Resolving address of majorchooser.info
2012-03-18 13:03:40 5608 2 Status: Connecting to 50.16.204.201:21...
2012-03-18 13:03:40 5608 2 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2012-03-18 13:03:41 5608 2 Response: 220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
2012-03-18 13:03:41 5608 2 Command: USER majorchooser
2012-03-18 13:03:41 5608 2 Response: 331 Please specify the password.
2012-03-18 13:03:41 5608 2 Command: PASS ***********
2012-03-18 13:03:42 5608 2 Response: 230 Login successful.
2012-03-18 13:03:42 5608 2 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2012-03-18 13:03:42 5608 2 Response: 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
2012-03-18 13:03:42 5608 2 Status: Connected
2012-03-18 13:03:42 5608 2 Status: Starting upload of D:\websites\tedxnanjing-online\wp-admin\admin-footer.php
2012-03-18 13:03:42 5608 2 Command: CWD /test-ftp/wp-admin
2012-03-18 13:03:43 5608 2 Response: 250 Directory successfully changed.
2012-03-18 13:03:43 5608 2 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2012-03-18 13:03:43 5608 2 Command: TYPE I
2012-03-18 13:03:43 5608 2 Response: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
2012-03-18 13:03:43 5608 2 Command: PASV
2012-03-18 13:03:44 5608 2 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (50,16,204,201,5,79).
2012-03-18 13:03:44 5608 2 Command: LIST -a
2012-03-18 13:03:45 5608 1 Error: Connection timed out
2012-03-18 13:03:45 5608 1 Error: File transfer failed
```

Comment: Network unstable?

Comment: what do you mean the server? cause i can use another ftp server without any trouble. i think there is something wrong when filezila try to upload two file altogether
**STOR admin-ajax.php**
**STOR admin-footer.php** and there is only one response:`226 Transfer complete.`

Comment: Filezilla just puts all child processes' outputs together. so I think the problem is still related to link quality.

Comment: i don't know , i try serveral server on amazon and rackspace in defferent size and location, still i got the error, but when i choose skip exsting files with filezilla,in the log the error still show up but  things seem to be fine.i can't let everyone using the server do the same, this is for now the best solution.